# incorrect sum result?

Tags: crystal-reports

I used to below formula to add up the pict exists but the result is 31 instead of 16. I have no idea why this is happening.

[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you have some grouping going on here? Could you add a little more detail to your question?

Answer (score 0):

On your Crystal Report

RightClick-->Insert Summary

In Choose the Field ---Select your field Name

In Calculate this Summary---Select SUM

In summary Location---Add your Location

Hope this helps